# wrapping specialised c++ template class with swig

Tags: c++, templates, swig

consider the following class declarations:

```
namespace X {
template<class T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    virtual ~Foo();

    T value() const;
};

template<class T>
class Foo<vector<T>> {
public:
    Foo();
    virtual ~Foo();

    T value( const int ) const;
};
}
```

for them i have the following declaration in the foo.i file

```
%include "stl.i"
%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_vector.i"

namespace X {
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    virtual ~Foo();
    T value() const;
};

template<class T>
class Foo<vector<T> > {
public:
    Foo();
    virtual ~Foo();
    T value( const int ) const;
};

%template(FooInt) Foo<int>;
%template(FooString) Foo<string>;
%template(FooVectorInt) Foo<vector<int> >;

}
```

the difference between the two classes is the specialisation of the later to vector container *and* the differrent signature of the value() method, where the first takes no arguments, while the second takes an expects an integer.

the wrapper code put together by swig wrapps the `%template(FooVectorInt)` wrong, in that it calls the `value()` method instead that of the specialised vector method `value(const int)`. giving me the following compile error message:

```
foo_wrap.cxx: in function »int _wrap_FooVectorInt_value(lua_State*)«:

/home/noobsaibot/foo/bindings/src/lua/foo_wrap.cxx:6706:81: error: no matching function to call »X::Foo<std::vector<int> >::value() const«
/home/noobsaibot/foo/src/foo.h:78:5: note: candidate is: T X::Foo<std::vector<_RealType> >::value(int) const [with T = int, int = unsigned int]
```

any advices as to what i might be missing to make swig understand which function is the correct one?

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want by doing:

```
%include "stl.i"
%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_vector.i"

namespace X {
using namespace std;

%rename(FooVectorInt) Foo<std::vector<int> >;

class Foo<std::vector<int> > {
public:
    virtual ~Foo();
    int value( const int ) const;
};

template<class T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    virtual ~Foo();
    T value() const;
};

%template(FooInt) Foo<int>;
%template(FooString) Foo<string>;
}
```

This works because what you write in the interface file *isn't* C++ and all that matters is that the correct code is generated by SWIG. If you want to repeat this lots you can write macros (which is close to what `%template` is anyway).

Still this isn't a very clean solution - I expected this to "just work" with the specialisations and I can't see a simpler workaround either.

Comment: forget what i wrote, i didn't get an error. now on to check whether it does what it is supposed to do :) ... thanks so far.

Comment: it compiles and i get the "correct" object Foo<vector<int>>, however, the type isn't known to lua ... rendering the object unusable inside lua :/ ...

Comment: @noobsaibot - what do you mean "not known to lua?" it looked like it was being registered properly in the Python test I did. (I've never used lua in my life)

Comment: never mind, i've refactored my code, so that the collection based class has a different name than the simple one. problem solved :)